# Dynamic div that expands horizontally

Tags: html, css

I understand how to do this with Javascript, but as of right now I am primarily focused on accomplishing this with css.

Example:

CSS

```
#parent {
   height: 200px;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
.child {
    height 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

$("#parent").on("click", function () {
    $(this).append("<div class='child'></div>");
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With this say your window size is only 600 px.  On the 4th child the div would need to expand.  I want that content to be hidden, but you can scroll horizontally to view it.

Comment: This is unclear, how do you want the .child elements to expand?

Comment: This is just a sample, it doesn't in anyway change the question.

Comment: #parent div:nth-of-type(3) may be of help, or probably better #bb span.child:nth-of-type(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene Xa had half of the answer.  white-space: nowrap only works on text.  So, in order for that to work on a div as the question asks, you must have the child set to inline-block;

```
#parent {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.child {
    height 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```